# Java Variable Not Changing Linux

Tags: java, linux, environment-variables

Hey guy's trying to figure out how to change my java variable on my ubuntu box.  I've altered the .bashrc and the /etc/profile to reflect

`export JAVA_HOME=/home/jerod/tools/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java
export JRE_HOME=/home/jerod/tools/java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:JAVA_HOME:JRE_HOME`

and when echoing any of them with echo $JAVA_HOME I get the appropriate response.  However when I type 
'java -version '

I get the following:

> java version "1.7.0_85"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.10.1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

How to I fix this?

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:JAVA_HOME:JRE_HOME` this sets the original path to be searched before `JAVA_HOME`, etc, so it probably finds the old java first.

Comment: echo path.. it must be having older java path.. remove that and try again

Comment: Check that the OS is using the correct path with "which java".

Comment: You seem to be missing the `$` sign before `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` in your path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/jerod/tools/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin
export JRE_HOME=/home/jerod/tools/java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre 
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
```

The **$** was missing in your **PATH** definition before **JAVA_HOME** and **JRE_HOME**.

It was put in after the system **PATH** so it would find **java** there before your path.

Also **PATH** is a list of folders separated by colons **:** and you had a full path to the **java** exectutable there.

**JRE_HOME** doesn't need to be in the path and should be to the path to the JRE directory.

Actually try that in a bash session interactively first to make sure it works first.  It should.

You can check as follows:

```
which java
```

Should return:

```
/home/jerod/tools/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java
```

And:

```
java -version
```

Should return the version output with 1.8.0_65 in it.

Comment: @sinisterrook does this answer your question? Equivalent steps work for me using an extracted JDK archive on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Sure did :) thats why I accepted it.